# Play audio source from script

Tags: c#, audio, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2017, soundeffect

I jumbled a few Tutorials together for my first simple game.

I have 2 audio sources under my GameObject that I use as the character. They both play via "play on awake". Only one plays from script. The other either doesn’t sound at all or gives a few clicks when called from script.

I am using the most current Visual Studio to write Scripts

Here's a portion of my script that isn't working correctly (I have left out a lot of player movement script).

audio variable on line 7, audio play on line 33

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{

public Rigidbody rb;

public AudioSource AudioFall;

public GameObject Fall;



if(rb.position.y < -1f)
{
AudioFall.Play();
Fall.SetActive(true);
FindObjectOfType<GameManager>().GameOver();
}
```

Here is a portion in a separate .cs that is working

audio variable on line 7, audio play on line 17

```
using UnityEngine;

public class playerCollision : MonoBehaviour
{
public PlayerMovement movement;

public AudioSource AudioCrash;

public GameObject Crash;

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collisionInfo)
{
    if (collisionInfo.collider.tag == "Obstacle")
    {
        FindObjectOfType<PlayerMovement>().rb.isKinematic = true;
        movement.enabled = false;
        AudioCrash.Play();
        Crash.SetActive(true);
        FindObjectOfType<GameManager>().GameOver();
    }

}
```

I have tried to increase max distance in the audiosource inspector.

Comment: You need to put `Debug.Log` inside `if(rb.position.y < -1f)` to see if that condition is even true and also to see how many times it is called.

Comment: @Programmer Thanks! so i tried this  if(rb.position.y < -1f)
        {
            Debug.Log(AudioFall.time);
            AudioFall.Play();
            Fall.SetActive(true);
            FindObjectOfType<GameManager>().GameOver();
        }

Comment: The result was this after i ran the Game Object off the the edge was five notes in the console [ UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object) 0, UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object) 0.021, UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object) 0, UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object) 0, UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object) 0  ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check these three things:

**1**.It looks like your audio is being played each frame while `if(rb.position.y < -1f)` is `true` since the `Debug.Log` is called multiple times. Simply check if it is playing before playing it:

```
if(rb.position.y < -1f)
{
    //PLAY ONLY IF AUDIO IS NOT PLAYING
    if (!AudioFall.isPlaying)
    {
        AudioFall.Play();
    }
    Fall.SetActive(true);
    FindObjectOfType<GameManager>().GameOver();
}
```

**2**.If that's not the case then please verify that audio clip is assigned to the clip slot of the AudioFall `Audiosource` in the Editor.

**3**.Finally, if the `Fall` GameObject is the-same as the GameObject the audio is attached to then the audio won't play because it being set to inactive. Check if it is being set in-active anywhere. You have to attach the AudioFall `Audiosource` to another empty GameObject that will not be deactivated.

Comment: It worked! Thanks so much. This isn't the first website I went to with my issue. Sooo much help!

Comment: Nice. Good luck with your game.

Comment: if you don't mind my asking, i went to unity's web page https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource-isPlaying.html but i can find out what the ! is for?

Comment: oh. wait. it means that the audio isn't playing. the opposite. like !=

Comment: `==` means `is` while `!=` means `not`. Also put `!` in front a boolean variable means `not`. I thin you should learn about logics in C# before making games.

Comment: That's what I'm doing. I just wanted to upgrade a tutorial. I am actually a musician that wants to break into to the game world. Appreciate all your help

Comment: Good. You can do it. I wish you luck in the programming world.